# Error 419: How is Laravel 10 different from Laravel 8?

Tags: php, laravel, bootstrap-5, laravel-10

I've been following a tutorial on Laravel 8 on Youtube as it is the best tutorial I've found about Laravel that works for me, despite working with Laravel 10 myself.
I understood the differences between Laravel mix and Vite and so many other things, but I've followed the tutorial, which is this one btw: "[Laravel 8 tutorial by Code with Dary](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=376vZ1wNYPA&list=PLFHz2csJcgk98RlS3y7ixAhIsUgTjGHIc)", and despite it working in Laravel 8, it doesn't work for my Laravel version.

It's a form that I've been trying to submit things to, but every time I click on the button, it doesn't get redirected to "/cars" and it shows a page "419 |
PAGE EXPIRED". I tried changing the "./cars" to a specific page, but it still doesn't work.

I also tried reading some answers on Stackoverflow, but it still didn't work. I wonder if it's because I'm using a newer version of Laravel.
this is my view:

```
@extends('../layouts.app')

@section('content')
<div class="d-flex justify-content-center col-12">

    <form action="/cars" method="POST">
        
    <h1>create car</h1>
        <div class="mb-3">
          <label for="exampleInputEmail1" class="form-label">Car name</label>
          <input type="text" class="form-control" id="exampleInputEmail1" aria-describedby="emailHelp">
        </div>
        <div class="mb-3">
          <label for="exampleInputPassword1" class="form-label">Year</label>
          <input type="text" class="form-control" id="exampleInputPassword1">
        </div>
        <div class="mb-3">
            <label for="exampleInputPassword1" class="form-label">Description</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="exampleInputPassword1">
          </div>
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
      </form>
    
</div>
@endsection
```

This is the simplified cars controller:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Models\Car;

    class CarsController extends Controller
    {
        /**
         * Display a listing of the resource.
         */
        public function index()
        {
    
            $cars= car::all();
            return view('cars.index',[
                'cars'=>$cars
            ]);
        }



        public function create()
        {
            return view('cars.create');
        }
    
        /**
         * Store a newly created resource in storage.
         */
        public function store(Request $request)
        {
            $car = Car::create([
                'name'=>$request->input('name'),
                'founded'=>$request->input('founded'),
                'description'=>$request->input('description')
            ]);
    
            return redirect('/cars');
        }
  
    }
```

Comment: It looks like you're missing the CSRF token field; https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/csrf

Adding `@csrf` to the form should fix the issue.

Comment: I added it to my HTML file's header and it made no changes.

Comment: can I just put @csrf before the form?

Comment: I think you need to put it inside the form. Check out the docs https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/csrf#preventing-csrf-requests

Comment: First fix this one: `@extends('../layouts.app')`, should be `@extends('layouts.app')`, it's a miracle that it's working, but ok.... second, yes, the @csrf, it should be inside your form. Always. Third you're posting to a route. Yes, `/cars` works, but try to learn standards. You're following a tutorial, so keep those things in mind. Fourth: Model names, class names start with an uppercase letter. I saw `cars` somewhere, so that's why I mentioned it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

419 page expired mean that the protection mechanism against CSRF attacks has been triggered and laravel is blocking your browser.it can happen with several reasons like a fallows,

step1

you forgot to include CSRF token to your form.so you can add it to your form using the `@csrf` blade directive.

```
<form action="/cars" method="POST">
@csrf
<!-- Your code -->
</form>
```

step 2

you can check your session configuration in your `.env` file to make sure that session driver, domain and lifetime are set correctly.

step 3

check your controller is configured correctly.
check your `CarsController@store` method is receiving and validating the request data.
and also you can use the `dd($request->all())` function to dump the request and see if it is working correctly.